# Mapping the link network between websites (blogs)?

Tags: webapp-rec

I wish to create a link map between blogs so to reflect the "social network" between bloggers.

Such a service would take a starting point of a blog or two, and start adding links and mapping the links between them.

Is there a web service to do this?

(I am sure I once found a service that does that - but can't find it at the moment)

Comment: Interesting question... could get a bit complex though. I know that in some blog software like Wordpress, you can specify what types of links you're using (rel="me" rel="friend" etc) but don't know where they get used.

Comment: Thanks.  It is complex, and I am unsure how to answer it myself.  Hence my question :)

Answer (score 1):

Google has a [social graph API](http://code.google.com/apis/socialgraph/) which can show you the graph of links bewteen bloggers etc. See it in use on the [example apps](http://code.google.com/apis/socialgraph/docs/examples.html) by entering a couple of example blogs in the box.

Answer (score 0):

there is a java-applet on [TouchGraph.com](http://www.touchgraph.com/TGGoogleBrowser.html), looks pretty nice. Use "link:yourblog.com" as query.

Comment: Thanks. I remember seeing this one.  I hope for more answers :)  Cheers, Tal